# Intersect 2 arrays jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way I can determine the intersection between 2 arrays where the indexing is different, like this:

```
a1 = ["a", "b"]
a2 = ["b", "a"]

/* a1 == a2 should return true */
```

and of course,

```
a1 = ["b", "c"]
a2 = ["d", "f"]

/* a1 == a2 should return false */
```

Or is there any better way to check the similarity between 2 arrays where indexing is different in jQuery/Javascript

Comment: Your answer is in the duplicate. Note that jQuery is a framework primarily intended for amending the DOM. As such it's not what you need to use here; plain old JS is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sort().toString()`

```js
var a1 = ["a", "b"]
var a2 = ["b", "a"]

console.log(a1.sort().toString()===a2.sort().toString());
```

```js
var a1 = ["b", "c"]
var a2 = ["d", "f"]
console.log(a1.sort().toString()===a2.sort().toString());
```